# Property 'detect' does not exist on type 'GraphModel'

Tags: angular, tensorflow, html5-video, tensorflow.js

I'm trying to use TensorFlow JS to create a real-time object detection app in Angular 13. I have a video element that records from the webcam, and I'm trying to call the `model.detect(video)` method as stated here: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflowjs-object-detection#7

However, I get an error that property 'detect' does not exist on type GraphModel. I'm not exactly sure if I have the type wrong, or if there is something else wrong with my setup. I do have the method 'predict' available, but that does not seem to accept a video stream as a parameter.
This is the code that I have so far:

```
export class ScannerComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
  @ViewChild('player') videoElement!: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('canvas') canvas!: ElementRef;
  streamTracks: MediaStreamTrack[] = [];
  video!: HTMLVideoElement;
  recording = false;
  model!: tf.GraphModel;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loadModel();
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.video = this.videoElement.nativeElement;
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(stream => {
      this.streamTracks = stream.getVideoTracks();
      this.video.srcObject = stream;
      this.video.play();
    })
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.streamTracks.forEach(track => {
      track.stop();
    });
  }

  async loadModel() {
    await tf.loadGraphModel(modelUrl).then((loadedModel: tf.GraphModel) => {
      this.model = loadedModel;
    });
  }

  toggleRecording(): void {
    this.recording = !this.recording;
    if (this.recording) {
      this.detectPuzzlePieces();
    }
  }

  detectPuzzlePieces(): void {
    // This is where I'm trying to call the detect method
    this.model.detect(this.video) // Error: Property 'detect' does not exist on type 'GraphModel'.ts(2339)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`detect()` is a method that is defined in some **JS module** that wraps actual `GraphModel` model execution with some additional pre and post processing.

If you want to run `GraphModel` directly, it has `predict()` and `executeAsync()` methods, depending on the model architecture and use-case.